# Mysql adding user for remote access

Tags: mysql, remote-access

I created user `user@'%'` with `password 'password`. But I can not connect with:

```
mysql_connect('localhost:3306', 'user', 'password');
```

When I created user `user@'localhost'`, I was able to connect. Why? Doesn't '%' mean from ANY host?

Comment: Note that the password for user@localhost and user@% is in general different, as well as privileges.

Answer (score 505, accepted):

In order to connect remotely, you have to have MySQL bind port 3306 to your machine's IP address in my.cnf. Then you have to have created the user in both localhost and '%' wildcard and grant permissions on all DB's as such *.* See below:

my.cnf (my.ini on windows)

```
#Replace xxx with your IP Address 
bind-address        = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Then:

```
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

Then:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Depending on your OS, you may have to open port 3306 to allow remote connections.

Comment: This helped me with using a WebFaction private MySQL instance. I followed your CREATE USER and GRANT ALL steps, set `mysql.default_port = <private instance port>` in my php.ini, and then used `127.0.0.1` throughout for my db hostname

Comment: Very useful. Just a comment. my.cnf could be including another configuration file so the relevant line may be somewhere else. In my.cnf look for a line beginning with !include, if bind-address is not in my.cnf it could be located in that included file.

Comment: Where is the my.cnf file?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running and what platform?? Linux, Windows??

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic on linux look in '/etc/mysql' could be also the file mysql.cnf though. See MSS instructions, too.

Comment: don't forget to FLUSH PRIVILEGES ;)

Comment: Also check **/etc/mysql/my.cnf** or  **/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf** location for changing **bind-address=0.0.0.0**

Comment: Why both localhost and % ?

Comment: @nights `localhost` is not needed for remote access.

Comment: @VishnuS.Divetia `0.0.0.0` is not mandatory. The IP address of the interface through which remote access will happen, is enough.

Comment: @volkovmqx `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` is not needed on creation of a user, just on `INSERT`, `DELETE` or `UPDATE` into user DB or privileges DB.

Comment: Needs to be done on the server side, although this seems obvious after hours of struggle.

Comment: This solution has a flaw. Existing users accessing the system with host=localhost will stop working

Comment: @ShahidKarimi do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 29):

Follow instructions (steps 1 to 3 aren't needed in Windows):

1. Find mysql config to edit:

> /etc/mysql/my.cnf (Mysql 5.5)

> /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf (Mysql 5.6+)

2. Find `bind-address=127.0.0.1` in config file change `bind-address=0.0.0.0` (you can set bind address to one of your interface IPs or like me use 0.0.0.0)
3. Restart mysql service run on console: `service mysql restart`
4. Create a user with a safe password for remote connection. To do this run following command in mysql (if you are linux user to reach mysql console run `mysql` and if you set password for root run `mysql -p`):

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'remote'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'safe_password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Now you should have a user with name of `user` and password of `safe_password` with capability of remote connect.

Comment: change bind-address=0.0.0.0... that worked for me. and grant privileges

Comment: allowing bind-address globally will lead to big security concern. instead-of we can add specific IP address or address range.

Comment: third step should be: service mysql restart

Comment: @quanly-mc you are right, I just fix it. thanks

Comment: @gururajender According to this post (https://serverfault.com/a/257517) , assuming you are going to allow external / non local connections at all, 0.0.0.0 is fine, and is even the default in later versions of mysql

Answer (score 15):

for what DB is the user? look at this example

```
mysql> create database databasename;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> grant all on databasename.* to cmsuser@localhost identified by 'password';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

so to return to you question the "%" operator means all computers in your network.

like aspesa shows I'm also sure that you have to create or update a user. look for all your mysql users:

```
SELECT user,password,host FROM user;
```

as soon as you got your user set up you should be able to connect like this:

```
mysql -h localhost -u cmsuser -p
```

hope it helps

Comment: generally, for all db. I just want to connect, not to select DB.
`code`mysql_connect('localhost:3306', 'user', 'password'); `code`

Comment: what OS are you on, Windows, Linux??

Comment: You will need to make sure your IP address is bound to port 3306. In windows you might use netstat -n to see what ports are bound to your IP. If you see 127.0.0.1:3306 you will not be able to connect from anything other than localhost

Answer (score 3):

I had used an existing user that had password using mysql_navtive_password

```
CREATE USER 'sammy'@'remote_server_ip' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Rather than

```
CREATE USER 'sammy'@'remote_server_ip' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

thus was not able to connect. Deleting a old one and creating a new without mysql_native_password did the trick

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is to use MySql Workbench.
Go to Administration -> Users and privileges -> and change 'localhost' with '%' in 'Limit to Host Matching' (From host) attribute for users you wont to give remote access Or create new user ( Add account button ) with '%' on this attribute instead localhost.