# Public IP Address as my hostname in mysql_connect()

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-connect

i want to connect my php application(here at my office) and my database is at my home,

```
mysql_connect('119.92.59.55','root','lester1992')
```

but they don't communicate each other(my comp & my office terminal), what maybe the posible problem?

here is the error i encountered.

> mysql_connect(): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287559/mysql-adding-user-for-remote-access
will helpful

Comment: Is the database actually reachable over the public internet? Are the ports open and properly forwarded? Actually, one would hope they are not. Putting a MySQL server on the public internet is a bad idea, unless you really know what you're doing and have set everything up very securely.

Comment: in mysql the authentication is host based. you should give permission for the office computer.

Comment: sir Girish Jangid i tried this already, but the problem i can't start my mysql :(

Comment: try `telnet your-home-ip 3306` if it is able to connect you have proper port forwarding in your router at home otherwise check router and firewall at your home to see if the connection to port 3306 is forwarded to the computer running MySQL server. (assuming you have not changed the default MySQL port). Also note changing the MySQL port used is better because you are putting it in the open.

Comment: sir bansi, i dont know how to telnet :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to give access permission in mysql to access from remote host.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
ON database.*
TO 'user'@'your_office_ip_address'
IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';
```

Comment: If it was because of user permissions, the error would say that.

Comment: noooo. never do this! giving permission for root from everywhere = open your computer and publish it in all media available

Comment: Changed '%' to 'your_office_ip_address' :)

Comment: Are you able to ping the ip address

Comment: Can you try to connect from a terminal. mysql -h <ip> -u username -p

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a MySQL database, three things must meet:

- Login
- Password
- Host

By default, `root` is configured to allow connections from the hostname `localhost` only. You can edit the table `mysql.user` and change `root`'s `Host` to `%` to allow connections from any peer.

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Host = '%' WHERE User = 'root';
```

Don't forget to run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` after that change in order to make it take effect immediately.

In addition, your firewall and router must be configured to make connections to port 3306 possible. You can use an online test tool such as [this one](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) to check if your port 3306 is reachable.

Comment: If it was because of user permissions, the error would say that.

Comment: Also allowing root to login from `%` is a superb security, don't you think so?

Comment: It will be as secure as your password make it be. And there are actually two plausible answers here, you might want to check the second one.

Answer (score 0):

By default, mysql is not allowing your user from your IP.

You want to allow access with a command similar to this (keep in mind this is very insecure):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
ON database.*
TO 'root'@'119.92.59.55'
IDENTIFIED BY 'lester1992';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to open your db for all ip's then you should assign rights to specific ip.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db.* TO 'user'@'your_office_ip' IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';
```

Note: You can get your office ip by below link, it will show you your current ip:

http://www.whatismyip.com/