# jit error while connecting to mysql remotly

Tags: c#, mysql, remote-access

i have enabled `mysql` to remote access and set a user with all grant permissions, and from typing what is my IP in `google` i get my public ip, my connection string is :

`SERVER=MY_PUBLIC_IP;PORT=3306;DATABASE=my_test;UID=myuser;PWD=xxxx;`

i changed the bind-address in my.ini as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287559/mysql-adding-user-for-remote-access) to my public ip, but i guess no matter what i do i still get that `jit` error which is:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
```

i try to connect with a c# form, note that the form work fine on my PC but i can't figure out a way to remote connect to the db in my computer from another PC, any help with that?

Comment: The answer to this question depends on what there is on the network between your computer and the remote computer.  Are they on the same office network or are you trying to connect across the public internet?  Have port 3306 been opened in any relevant firewalls?

Comment: there are separate by distance, i did shut the firewall of the two computer and nothing but the same error

Comment: How do the two computers connect to the internet?  For example, I connect via a broadband router.  The IP address I get when I ask Google is the IP address of the router, not of my PC.  My PC doesn't have a public IP address.

Comment: i connect with router,is this the way to get my router ip? [link](http://kb.linksys.com/Linksys/GetArticle.aspx?docid=4a3527c394744e7ba4a433c3499ecc85_Checking_the_Router_s_IP_Address_when_Using_Windows_7.xml&pid=80)

Comment: That tells you how to find the IP address of the router.  If the PC with MySQL is behind this router, then what you are asking for is quite simply not possible.