# Setting an external database for WordPress from wp_config file

Tags: mysql, wordpress, database-connection

**Problem:**

How to use an external database, that is not located in localhost, by setting the WordPress configuration in the file  *wp_config*.

So, all WordPress files (wp_content, wp_admin, ...) are in *Local computer A*, and the database is in *Server B*.

Can this be done ?, how would the settings be ?

**What I have tried:**

```
define('DB_HOST', 'example');
define('DB_HOST', 'example.com');
define('DB_HOST', 'http://example.com');
define('DB_HOST', 'example.com:22');
```

**Notes:**

- The server is  using MySQL on Linux.
- When I change the configuration, to use a local database, it works perfect. So it is not WordPress, is the connection setting.
- username, password, and database name (DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) are correct.

**Current error:**

> Error establishing a database connection

**Related links:**

http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/connect-local-wordpress-site-to-remote-database

http://digwp.com/2010/08/pimp-your-wp-config-php/

Comment: Does the database user that you are using have permission to connect remotely? See [this thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/setting-up-wp-with-remote-database?replies=4) and [this Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287559/mysql-adding-user-for-remote-access).

Comment: @wanasten sounds good, my first guess is that `root` has remote permissions, but I'm gonna check it, do you know how to check that ?

Comment: `root` probably doesn't have them by default. If you're using phpMyAdmin: log in and click the **Users** tab, the allowed hosts will be displayed in the **Hosts** column.

Answer (score 0):

To start the diagnosis, I would do the following :

- Try to connect to the DB with the user you have from another device. If you can, we are able to rule out the connectivity problem / remote access right on the DB side. Be sure to allow the mySql listening port through any firewall you may have
- `define('DB_HOST', 'example.com:port');` is the correct format. Can you try to use the IP address? Also mySql listen on port 3306 by default.
- Quite unlikely but also check the outbound connection from your WP host to the DB server / mySql port