# Recover my root user's DBA privileges on MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, centos, mariadb

I accidentally removed the DBA privileges of my only user from mariadb and now I can't use my bank and I was also unable to restore the privileges using the Linux SHELL CentOS 7.

Command I tried:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

return:

```
#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Has anyone ever experienced this?

Comment: See [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193854/cannot-reset-mysql-default-root-password-after-initial-installation) on dba.stackexchange for details on how to reset the password.

Comment: @Dave unsuccessful, the tip is password recovery, I know the password. My problem is that my root user has no DBA but has no privileges and that is what I want to restore.

Comment: I'd like to "bump" this question as I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: What server version do you use? I also doubt that the error message above is returned when you send the GRANT statement, it looks more like a login attempt from command line client.

Answer (score 2):

It's a wrong assumption that the wildcard for hostname also includes localhost, so an attempt to connect via socket (localhost) will fail:

```
mysql> create user 'foo'@'%' identified by 'bar';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,01 sec)

$mysql -ufoo -pbar -e"select current_user"
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'foo'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

When creating the user with localhost, everything works as expected:

```
mysql> create user 'foo'@'localhost' identified by 'bar';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,01 sec)

$ mysql -ufoo -pbar -e"select current_user\G"
*************************** 1. row ***************************
current_user: foo@localhost
```

Also beginning with MariaDB Server 10.4 (Posix platforms) the default authentication method for the root user (when connecting via localhost) happens via unix_socket plugin. This allows the root@localhost user to login without a password via the local Unix socket file defined by the socket system variable, as long as the login is attempted from a process owned by the operating system root user account:

```
mysql -e"show grants for root@localhost\G"
*************************** 1. row ***************************
Grants for root@localhost: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `root`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password USING 'invalid' OR unix_socket WITH GRANT OPTION
```

So a normal login as root will fail:

```
georg@mozart:~/mariadb$ mysql -uroot -e"select current_user()\G"
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

While running as root (sudo) login works as expected:

```
georg@mozart:~/mariadb$ sudo mysql -uroot -e"select current_user()\G"
*************************** 1. row ***************************
current_user(): root@localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

Stop MariaDb server

`sudo systemctl stop mariadb`

Restart DB without permission checking - [more](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-reset-your-mysql-or-mariadb-root-password)

`sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &`

`mysql -u root` enter password

reload the grant tables

`Mariadb[MYSQL]> FLUSH PRIVILEGES`

```
insert into user (Host, User, Password, Select_priv, Insert_priv, Update_priv, Delete_priv, Create_priv, Drop_priv, Reload_priv, Shutdown_priv, Process_priv, File_priv, Grant_priv, References_priv, Index_priv, Alter_priv, Show_db_priv, Super_priv, Create_tmp_table_priv, Lock_tables_priv, Execute_priv, Repl_slave_priv, Repl_client_priv, Create_view_priv, Show_view_priv, Create_routine_priv, Alter_routine_priv, Create_user_priv, ssl_type, ssl_cipher, x509_issuer, x509_subject, max_questions, max_updates, max_connections, max_user_connections) 
values('localhost','root','','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','','','','','0','0','0','0');
```

Then restart database

`sudo systemctl start mariadb`
I hope this works for you. it did work for me.

You can explore answers on [Grant privileges on MariaDB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27130069/6800539)

Comment: Instead of using `GRANT` and `CREATE USER` statements people frequently bork their database configuration by modifying system tables directly. This is not possible anymore in recent versions of MariaDB, since these tables became non-insertable views.