# Connect to mySQL with python 3

Tags: mysql, database

I have a problem with mySQL

I installed it on my raspberry pi - python 3 virtual environment with the following command:

```
sudo pip install mysql-connector
```

I have the following script:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="127.0.0.1",
    port="11300",
    user="pi",
    passwd="1234"
 )

print(mydb)
```

But nothing happens, no error, no connection, ... I found the port number with the command 'netstat' under TCP connection

Comment: That means its working so go ahead and do something do some query etc..

Comment: I was expecting something like `<mysql.connector.connection.MySQLConnection object ar 0x16645F0>` but ok, I did another test with `mycursor = mydb.cursor()` and `mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE myDatabase")` and after this, search for the database: `mycursor.execute("SHOW DATABASE")` but still nothing happens...

Comment: you have to fetch to see response of your query

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20959654/6813858 would be helpful

Comment: I read those comments, and tried some things out, but still nothing happens...

Answer (score 1):

after `execute` you need to open cursor, to get result
you can open cursors like:

`mycursor.fetchall()` returns iterable object.

```
for row in mycursor.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

`mycursor.fetchone()` fetches first row from result

```
print(mycursor.fetchone())
```

P.S. are you sure that you've installed that package properly?

e.g.: for ubuntu you can install this package for python3 by typing:

`apt install python3-mysql.connector`

Comment: The installation was successful, When I type `mysql --help` in the prompt, and look at `port` I have a value `0` is this normal? and now with `netstat` I don't see the TCP/IP anymore ??

Comment: port value `0` is normal. you've executed `mycursor.execute("SHOW DATABASE")` can you please try: `mycursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")` and get rows by opening cursor

Comment: this is what I have `import mysql.connector

try: 
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(user='pi',password='1234',host='127.0.0.1',port='11300',database='test')
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")
    mycursor.fetchall()

except:
    print("error")` But still I got nothing, It's like the prompt is waiting for something, but I can do anything..

Comment: after executing try running this:
`for row in mycursor.fetchall(): print(row)`

Comment: @WerbrouckBram I've edited main answer, check examples there

Comment: still the same problem. Is there a way to check the connections/settings/... ?

Comment: you can use `mydb.is_connected()` to get info about connected or not,
You can disconnect `mydb.disconnect()` and connect: `mydb.connect()`

Comment: btw can you connect directly to mysql console?
`mysql -u pi -p -P 11300` enter and then type password

Comment: I tried port 3306 again and now have the following error: `mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'pi'@'localhost'`

Comment: Seems like you have mysql on port `3306`. but strange, if you specify wrong port, `mysql.connector` should throw an exception: `mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError`

Comment: `sudo mysql -u pi -p` gives me an option to enter a password? I tried my normal login password from the raspberry, but when I hit enter, I got the message again`mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'pi'@'localhost'`

Comment: and what if you connect using port? `sudo mysql -u pi -p -P 11300`

Comment: THen I have to enter a password (so I take the same pasword which I use to log in into the raspberry pi) but... access denied :(

Comment: I found something: I think but have no id what to do with it.. `MariaDB [mysql]> SELECT User, host, plugin FROM mysql.user;
+------+-----------+-------------+
| User | host      | plugin      |
+------+-----------+-------------+
| root | localhost | unix_socket |
`

Comment: hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287559/mysql-adding-user-for-remote-access) helps