# MySql Login error - Domain name added automatically with the user name

Tags: mysql, windows, jdbc, jmeter

I am on Windows 10 desktop with a Cloudera VM running on it.
From inside the coudera vm Linux OS, I can login to MySQL with:

```
mysql -ucloudera -pcloudera
```

When I try to connect to the MySQL inside Cloudera VM from my windows machine, using JDBC, I get this error: (my windows computer name is a TV with no domain name)

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'cloudera'@'tv.lan' (using password: YES))
```

> jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/infa_mdm user = cloudera
>   password = cloudera

How do I disable this automatic addition of domain name at the end?
Or is there any other way to resolve this?

Below is Apache JMeter's JDBC connection config:
[image]

Comment: I avoided the problem for now, by adding a mysql user with the domain name and GRANTed all privileges as per: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287559/mysql-adding-user-for-remote-access/37341046

But that would not solve the problem in a real life project.

Comment: I am using Apache JMeter's JDBC Config to setup the JDBC connection ( edited Question to include the photo of JDBC connection).
there are few text boxes:
URL = jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/infa_mdm
User = cloudera, Pass = cloudera

Comment: AFAIK you can't, because - again AFAIK - it is determined by MySQL server, not by the client (if the client could, that would be a severe security issue). You'll need to explicitly grant to this combination (or grant to the less secure `'cloudera'@'%'`). It works in the first case because MySQL will infer that as `'cloudera'@'localhost'` or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GRANT privilegies to 'cloudera'@'tv.lan'
Thats because of MySQL's have the host based permission. Each `Username` and its `Hostname` stored in a separate column in the `mysql.users` table, so if you want to be able to log in to MySQL from `tv.lan` computer on behalf of `cloudera` user, you need to give access permission to this user and this hostname -

As [documentation says](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-user.html):

> An account when first created has no privileges and a default role of NONE. To assign privileges or roles, use the GRANT statement.
>
> Each account name uses the format described in Section 6.2.4, “Specifying Account Names”. For example:
>
> ```
> CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
> ```
>
> The host name part of the account name, if omitted, defaults to '%'.

Check this Data Base JMeter testing tips for additional information:
 - [Building a Database Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html#building)
 - [JMeter Database Testing](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/07/jmeter-database-testing/)
 - [JMeter Cloud testing your DB](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2015/02/jmeter-cloud-testing-your-db/)