# Qt access raspberry pi mysql database

Tags: mysql, qt, ssh, raspberry-pi, qsqldatabase

I would like to create an application that runs on a PC and connects to the mysql mariadb on my raspberry pi. I already managed to set it up on MySQL workbench, with the SSH connection options. However, I'd like to know how I can connect my app to that database.

Let's say my SSH is the default:
username: pi
password: raspberry

and for my database:
host: localhost
username: root
password: Admin123

(these aren't the real logins, don't worry ;), but I don't feel like sharing the real information )

What would the code look like?

I'm familiar with

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setHostName("localhost");
db.setDatabaseName("mydb");
db.setUserName("root");
db.setPassword("Admin123");
bool ok = db.open();
```

Comment: How do you physically connect your RPI device to the host?

Comment: If you want to access the db it is in the RPI from your PC then you can no longer use "localhost" but the IP of the RPI.

Comment: Alright, so if the database is on the local host of the raspberry pi and the pi is on 10.0.3.36, then I need to fill in 10.0.3.36? Or do I need to fill in 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

`127.0.0.1` is the loopback adapter IP address. It is always the IP address of the own host but not a remote address. So, if you are sure that the 10.0.3.36 is the IP address of the RPI, then you will be happy with that.

You should also make sure that MySQL port (likely to be 3306) is not firewalled on your RPI and [the MySQL server accepts remote host connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287559/mysql-adding-user-for-remote-access/16287647) for the user you are trying to connect with.

This [tutorial](https://howtoraspberrypi.com/enable-mysql-remote-connection-raspberry-pi/) may help you as well.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will look into that!