# Mysql server not accessing remotely

Tags: mysql, remote-access

I added the binding to the my.ini file

bind-address = 0.0.0.0

Also created a user

GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%';

in windows firewall, made sure that the inbound rule had port 3306 allowed

then I tried connecting over internet. In my workbench,
host: public ip of the remote host
user: myuser@%, password: password of the user

Still, the mysqlbench is not able to connect

I tried connecting command prompt too but it does not seem to work

Any other hints what am I still missing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysql adding user for remote access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287559/mysql-adding-user-for-remote-access)

Comment: If the linked question doesn't answer your question, you may check your router's firewall and do some port scanning to identify the issue.

Comment: "other hints what am I still missing here?" - publicly accessible mysql instances aren't a good idea. MySQL's authentication can be brute forced. Using a SSH based connection that workbench supports would be a more secure way to do this. Use exact error messages rather than 'does not seem to work'.

Comment: Its a dev environment and we are only testing and stress testing the system. security would be the next step to consider but before all, we want the mysql accessible over the internet.